weasyprint "Document has no attribute write_png"
I am writing a webapp in Python and Django. I use weasyprint to write pdf documents and I would like to use write_png() to get a png thumbnail of each pdf.
This is from my views.py:
pdf_letter = weasyprint.HTML(string=letter, base_url=static_url).render(
                stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(static_url + "/abrechnung/css/print-portrait.css")]
                )
pdf_table = weasyprint.HTML(string=table).render(
                stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(static_url + "/abrechnung/css/print-landscape.css")]
                )
val = []
for doc in pdf_letter, pdf_table:
    for p in doc.pages:
        val.append(p)
    pdf_file = pdf_letter.copy(val).write_pdf(f"{datetime.now()}.pdf")
    thumbnail = pdf_letter.copy(val).write_png(f"{datetime.now()}.png")

When I try to run the program, I get the following error message in the browser:

'Document' object has no attribute 'write_png'

pdf_file = pdf_letter.copy(val).write_pdf(f"{datetime.now()}.pdf")
thumbnail = pdf_letter.copy(val).write_png(f"{datetime.now()}.png")
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

The weasyprint documentation on the write_png() function can be found here:
https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/v52.5/api.html#weasyprint.document.Document.write_png
As I read the weasyprint documentation, I states that
weasyprint.HTML.render() produces a weasyprint.document.Document.
Said object has a function write_png().
Soooo.... WTF? What am I doing wrong here?
I tried this
for i, page in enumerate(document.pages):
    document.copy([page]).write_png('page_%s.png' % i)

and this
for page in document.pages:
        yield document.copy([page]).write_png()

from the weasyprint tutorial (variables etc. adapted to my code of course) but none of both worked - I got the same error.
Writing the pdf file alone is no problem, it is saved and returned later on. Problems just started when I tried to add the thumbnail functionality.

The documentation clearly states that write_png is a valid method. Check that you have the latest version installed.

I just checked it. My version is 61.2 from March 8th 2024. This is also the newest available version on PyPi. Newest version of weasyprint is 62.1 from May 6th 2024, but there are no changes to write_png() stated in the changelog since 61.2

After more digging, I finally found the answer myself: They dropped write_png() in 2021 and nobody cared to change the documentation...
Here's a blog article on the topic:
https://www.courtbouillon.org/blog/00008-weasyprint-53-beta/
